# Is there any way to force bash to ignore and hide Cassandra warnings?

Tags: bash, shell, cassandra

basically title, is there any command that can ignore and force bash not to print out the warning(s), similar to `warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")` in python? thanks!

edit: the warning is `WARNING: Could not connect to the JMX on localhost:8080, information won't be shown.`, but it does not effect the result of my program so it's not really important.

Comment: command 2> /dev/null   THis will only suppress std errs not the output.

Comment: you want to ignore warnings, or want to change the log level?

Comment: ty all! 2>/dev/null  works as what I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

redirecting error to /dev/null

```
command-here 2>/dev/null
```

*(thnx @RandomUser)*

---

redirecting error and output messages to a log file

```
command-here > myapp.log 2>&1
```

---

```
> file        redirects stdout to file
> /dev/null   redirects stdout to to the null device (discards it)

1> file       redirects stdout to file
2> file       redirects stderr to file
&> file       redirects stdout and stderr to file

/dev/null is the null device it takes any input you want and throws it away.
It can be used to suppress any output.
```

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/06/what-does-devnull-21-mean/

https://askubuntu.com/questions/350208/what-does-2-dev-null-mean

---

As @piyushj comment, you can try and change Cassandra log level altogether.
Cassandra uses the standard Java log library Log4j

Need to edit the log4jserver.properties file, and change the line

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,stdout,R
```

you can change the logging level to INFO, DEBUG, WARN, ERROR, or FATAL.

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2169293

Comment: I think this will redirect both std err and o/p, which is not OP asked.